# How to select default button in wpf dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I am creating a WPF dialog. It is like our normal `messagebox` with `ok` and `cancel` button. How to create such a dialog so that the `Ok` button is selected when the dialog is opened?

Comment: set the IsDefault=True for the OK button

Comment: It only enables save on Enter button but not showing button is selected

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**To set a Window's Default button**

Set your default button's [IsDefault property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) to true.

Note that you can also set a Window's Cancel button by setting a button's [IsCancel property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.iscancel.aspx) to true.

---

**To set the Selected (focused) button in a Window**

If you want to select a particular button then use the Focus method like this:

```
yourButton.Focus();
```

You might do this when a Window loads (in the Window_Loaded event).

To select a particular button when your Window opens make sure its [IsTabStop property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop.aspx) is set to true and ensure its [TabIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex.aspx) is lower than any other control on the Window.

Comment: Thnx for the help but is doesnt work . .it doesnt showing the button is selected it only enables enter button

any alternatives ??

Comment: @iamabhiee Edited to set the focus on a button.  HTH.

Answer (score 2):

just create a new button template and change the look and feel for the IsDefault=Tue state.
I just created a style and modified the state.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
x:Class="WpfApplication7.Window3"
x:Name="Window"
Title="Window3"
Width="640" Height="480" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=test}">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2"
                    Stroke="red" StrokeThickness="1"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="true"  StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF040000" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF7A7A7A" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE7E7E7" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA76F6F" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE7E7E7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsDefault" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC2BE5B" Offset="0.007"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE7E7E7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF01641D"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF528159" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE7E7E7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="test" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="130,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" IsDefault="True"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="26" Margin="298,157,162,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="26" Margin="0,157,-6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about IsDefault?

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand}"
        Content="My Button Text"
        IsDefault="True"/>
```