# IsDefault causes focus instead of click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a control with 3 text boxes and one `Button` that is set to `IsDefault`. When I am typing in one of the text boxes and press the Enter key I expect the `IsDefault` button to be clicked, instead it only focuses the button instead of clicking it. I have made sure that there are no other `IsDefault` buttons, I have checked that the `IsDefaulted` property of the `Button` is true when I press the enter button.

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="New:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox UndoLimit="10" Name="txtAddNew" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Amendment:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox UndoLimit="10" Name="txtAddAmend" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Unknown:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBox UndoLimit="10" Name="txtAddUnknown" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>

    <Idyllic:IdyllicButton DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,5" IsDefault="True" Name="btnAdd" Height="30" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <StackPanel>
            <Idyllic:CustomFillImage Image="{StaticResource Add}" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Idyllic:IdyllicButton>
</Grid>
```

[image]

EDIT: The proposed question as duplication does not fix the issue, I do not want to set the focus of the button, that is my issue. When I press enter the button is focused instead of clicked. My button is already set to IsDefault.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select default button in wpf dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593231/how-to-select-default-button-in-wpf-dialog)

Comment: did you checked with normal button,whether the issue exists with that too?

Comment: In the XAML you provided there's no event or command on that button. Are you sure it is supposed to do something when clicked?

Comment: @Nikita, I use the same control on another page with `IsDefault` and it works.

Comment: @Jcl, good eyes, I have a command control that is bound to the click event of that button and it is handled in my VM, not on the control. As state above it works on another page.

Comment: So if you actually click the button with your mouse (instead of pressing enter), it does what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @Jcl, yes it does, also if I press enter twice (one for focus, one to click) it does as intended.

Comment: I see, then I'm out of ideas, sorry... if it didn't actually focus on the first press of enter, I may have thought there was something else trapping enter... but since it focuses, then this is pretty strange. There's probably something else in your project which is preventing the correct behaviour, but hard to see without seeing it. Any exceptions or messages on the VS output window on the first enter press?

Comment: No errors in the output, I have removed all other buttons from the control and the issue persists.

Comment: See my answer posted if interested.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the problem was that there was another `User Control` embedded in the control that also implements `IsDefault`, I suppose in that case the behavior is to focus the first `IsDefault` button on the page, including child `User Controls`.

Comment: So the following claim `I have made sure that there are no other IsDefault buttons` in the question wasn't true. Since the `IsDefault` context is `Window`, everyone would assume `there` means window, not the control you are talking about.